# What is the relationship between Gwei and gas?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, gas-price, fees

I know that a Gwei means 1000000000 wei, but when we send a transaction with 21000 gas, is that mean we send 21000 Gwei? please explain Gwei for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gas is needed by miners to execute a transaction. The more complicated a transaction is, the more gas they will need.

When you send a transaction, you (or your wallet program) has to configure two things:

- The gas limit in `gas`: The maximum amount of gas that the transaction is allowed to consume
- The gas price in `Gwei/gas`: How much Gwei you're willing to pay per unit of gas

Multiplying these numbers together gives you the maximum transaction fee you're willing to pay for the transaction in `Gwei`.

If you set the gas price to `1 Gwei/gas`, a transaction with a gas limit of `21000 gas` will cost you a maximum of `21000 Gwei`.

Comment: So, is Gwei equal to gas?

Comment: @zediziza Only in transactions where the sender set the gas price equal to `1 Gwei/gas`. In transactions where the gas price is `15 Gwei/gas`, `1 gas` is equal to `15 Gwei`.

Comment: So why we need create separate field instead of one. thanks.